# How to get simple threading to work Python

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, concurrency, python-requests

i want to know how i can add simple threading to my code. At the moment it checks just one by one, and if some site isnt reachable it will wait for the timeout before it will continue with the next one this slows everything down.

```
import requests
import sys
import time
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)


with open("websites.txt", 'r') as websites:
    websites = websites.read().splitlines()

with open("para1.txt", 'r') as para1:
    para1 = para1.read().splitlines()

with open("para2.txt", 'r') as para2:
   para2 = para2.read().splitlines()

def main():
    for i in para1:
        for j in para2:
            for m in websites:
                try:
                    res = requests.get(m + i + j, verify=False, timeout=10)
                    print(m + i + j)
                    if res.status_code == 200:
                        print('Yes')
                    else:
                        print('No')
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    sys.exit()
                finally:
                    res.close()
                    time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) moving part of code which perform requests to separate function and pass it as argument:

```py
import urllib3
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

def check_func(url):
    response = requests.get(url, verify=False, timeout=10)
    return response.status_code == 200
    
def main():
    with open("websites.txt") as website_f, open("para1.txt") as para1_f,
        open("para2.txt", 'r') as para2_f, ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        tasks = {}
        for website in website_f:
            for para1 in para1_f:
                for para2 in para2_f:
                    url = website.rstrip() + para1.rstrip() + para2.rstrip()
                    tasks[executor.submit(check_func, url)] = url

        for task in as_completed(tasks):
            url = tasks[task]
            try:
                result = task.result()
            except KeyboardInterrupt:  # handling Ctrl + C
                for task in tasks:
                    task.cancel()      # won't cancel already finished or pending futures
            except CancelledError:     # will never happen (normally)
                pass                            
            except Exception as e:
                print(url, "-", "ERROR", e)
            else:
                print(url, "-", "GOOD" if result else "BAD")
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

*P.S. I haven't tested entire code so if there're any problems with it - write in comments.*

Comment: thank you for your answer, well the threading is working and its really fast now, but the script doesn't work correctly anymore. I dont know why but now it will only check the first entry from "websites.txt" with the first entry from "para1.txt" until all entry from "para2.txt" finished

Comment: In the script without threading it would check entry one from "website.txt" with entry one from "para1.txt" and "para2.txt" then it checks entry 2 from "website.txt" with entry one from "para1.txt" and entry 1 from "para2.txt"

Comment: @tadeu244, change loop order to match with your example